# How to get permission in android app?

Tags: java, android

I have problem with getting permission to save file from raw on phone. I have in manifest this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

In java where I'm using onclick I have function to save file

```
saveTestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

                InputStream in = null;
                FileOutputStream fout = null;
                try {
                    in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.testsound);
                    String downloadsDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
                    String filename = "testsound.mp3";
                    fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(downloadsDirectoryPath + filename));

                    final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                    int count;
                    while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                        fout.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (in != null) {
                        try {
                            in.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    if (fout != null) {
                        try {
                            fout.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
        }

    });
```

And that to check permission:

```
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };
public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
}
```

And when I try to save this file by click the button in app I'm getting error:

> W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Downloadtestsound.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

What is wrong?

Comment: Aren't you missing a slash after Download folder?

Comment: In other words,  you don't have root access

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47842968/7557205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is your problem:

```
fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(downloadsDirectoryPath + filename));
```

Use the below instead:

```
fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(downloadsDirectoryPath , filename));
```

You have permission only to `/storage/emulated/0/Download/testsound.mp3` and not `/storage/emulated/0/Downloadtestsound.mp3`

Comment: Hmmm, that change the error to /storage/emulated/0/Download/testsound.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: @Johnystrawits Could you try changing your target sdk version to 21 and check again?

Comment: I set up target sdk to 21 but I'm still getting this error :/

Answer (score 1):

put "/" between `filename` and `downloadsDirectoryPath` that's why it giving error .for testing if you don't get permissions then go to settings and check there manually grant permission and launch again.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        InputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        try {
            in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.testsound);
            String downloadsDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
            String filename = "testsound.mp3";
            fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(downloadsDirectoryPath + "/"+filename));

            final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                fout.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (fout != null) {
                try {
                    fout.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
}

});
```