# app crashing when using location permission

Tags: android, google-location-services

I am very new to android development and java. I am trying to learn some android code from [Build your first app](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html).
Now, the problem is, as soon as I add `FusedLocation`(the commanted section in the send code), it crashes. The current state of the code is (mostly the first app, and few line from [getting the last location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)) is:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and

**DisplayMessageActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        //Location
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);                        
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);
    }
}
```

The building of the app goes without error, but when app in `avd` crashes when I press send button. The app launching log is:

```
02/08 13:00:44: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t -p com.example.myfirstapp /home/rudra/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstApp/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_9.apk 
Split APKs installed
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 6972 on device emulator-5554
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9fe040c0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9fe040c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9fe032c0)
```

> ```
> E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
> E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
> E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
> E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
> ```

```
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9fe040c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9fe032c0)
V/View: dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring 0 children of 1073741830
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2144 bytes, containing 1 windows, 8 views
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=27KB, data=30KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=27KB, data=30KB
I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
```

(The quoted section in this log is in red color, possibly error.)

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp">
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
                android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Also, please tell me, if I can put the `location` in the textview as string.

**Update**
After adding the permission, my DisplayMessege is:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
           Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
           != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
       if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
               Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

           // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
           // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
           // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
           new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                   .setTitle(R.string.title_location_permission)
                   .setMessage(R.string.text_location_permission)
                   .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_dialog_location, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                           //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PlaceOrder.this,
                                   new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                   MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                       }
                   })
                   .create()
                   .show();


       } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        //Location
        if (checkLocationPermission()) {

            mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                            if (location != null) {
                                // Logic to handle location object
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location Permision is not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        }

        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);
    }
}
```

Which is giving build error:

```
/home/rudra/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstApp/app/src/main/java/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java
Error:(13, 8) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(30, 31) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(35, 24) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(41, 8) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(46, 9) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(48, 5) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(50, 5) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(89, 25) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(89, 33) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(91, 1) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

I know this is idotic and i am doing some silly error, but kindly help
Regards,

Comment: have yu added runtime permission request? which os version are you testing on?

Comment: I am using it on avd 27. How can I runtime permission request? Kindly explain.

Comment: you need to have runtime permission request , can you share your manifest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47842968/7557205 Follow this. This is my answer to another question regarding EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. So instead of EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission you may have to use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission. Don't forget add permission in manifest.

Comment: @AbdulKawee: Manifest is added

Comment: @BaRud please use the code i shared below in the answer it will work great i am using it ,and tell me if it helps you :) happy coding

Comment: @Zoe: the possible duplicate is due to the fact that permission is not added in manifest. In this case, this is already added.

Comment: @BaRud I have no clue where you got that from. The permission the OP in the other question is trying to use is declared in the manifest but still doesn't work... Read it again

Comment: @AbdulKawee: kindly check the updated answer

Comment: go to project directory->app delete build folder , and rebuild project

Comment: ok...thanks. But kindly tell me if I have copied and placed them correctly.

Comment: @BaRud did your problem resolved?

Comment: nope... and have no idea how to proceed, given that with your detail code, i cant run it. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to as for location permission in runtime.

```
 public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.title_location_permission)
                    .setMessage(R.string.text_location_permission)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_dialog_location, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PlaceOrder.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and simply use this code

```
if (checkLocationPermission()){
            //do your work

        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location Permision is not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: when i copy-paste this code to my code, I am getting large number of red underline, indicating some error in it, isnt it? can you please check?

Comment: yes , the one that will be like error caused by something like this and with activity name please share that